# Drag marks when feathering joint compound

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall, drywall-mud, mudding

When I try to feather joint compound around the edges of my room I get what appear to be lines every half inch or so that seems to be drag marks. I'm using a clean 6" knife on the first coat, all purpose mud, and I'm bending one edge of the knife to taper/feather (as shown here: https://youtu.be/nwTKWZk6e50?si=4xC3lmzfYquhNmGU). I'm trying to pull the knife in one smooth motion. Any ideas on how to get a smooth finish when feathering?

Comment: I seen the video, I never prefill my joints at all, unless they are 1/2" wide or so. The only thing that will leave drag marks in you finish is 1) a knife with a ding in the edge. 2) dry mud in the mix from it drying, and flaking off and dropping in the mix you are using. 3) Not cleaning the tags off the wall left by the prior coat of mud. Always go over the walls/joints with a broad knife to remove tags or a light pass with a drywall sander and 4) Taking too long to use the mud in the pan, or not cleaning it out well enough between refills to keep the dry crumbs from getting into the finish.

Comment: Size your knife for the joint, I use a 4" knife for all taping and finishing inside corners. A 6" knife for finishing ends of wall sections that are less than 6" wide. I use a 12" knife for that as well, it depends on how I feel at the time. A 12" is used for the broad joints, both my 6"anf 12" blades are curved so I can use the appropriate side to build up or flatten out. If you are using a 6" knife for broad joints, that will leave a ton of drag marks I finish broad joints in 3 widths of my 12" knife. One on either side, let dry, then one down the middle, let dry, then a tight skim over all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Feathering** and **6" knife** are not exactly things that go together.

**12" or 16" knife** goes with **feathering**

and

**6" knife** goes with **getting a first coat over the tape.** Which you let dry and then come back with a 10 or 12", (which will fill in any little lines) and let dry, and then come back with a 16 or 18" to finish/feather